# How to get a correctly rotated UIImage from an ALAssetRepresentation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, alassetslibrary, alasset

I’m trying to get a correctly rotated `UIImage` from an `ALAssetRepresentation` using the `fullScreenImage` method. I have several testing photos shot in various device orientations; the photos show up correctly in the Photos app. The documentation for `fullScreenImage` says:

> In iOS 5 and later, this method returns a fully cropped, rotated, and
>   adjusted image—exactly as a user would see in Photos or in the image
>   picker.
>
> To create a correctly-rotated `UIImage` object from the `CGImage`, you use
>   `imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:` or
>   `initWithCGImage:scale:orientation:`, passing the values of `orientation`
>   and `scale`.

Given the docs, my code looks like this:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
UIImage *img = [UIImage
    imageWithCGImage:[rep fullScreenImage]
    scale:[rep scale]
    orientation:[rep orientation]];
```

But the resulting `UIImage`’s rotation is wrong. When I replace `[rep orientation]` with `UIImageOrientationUp`, the image is fine for all testing photos. Obviously I’m hesitating to stick with this “solution”, as it feels like a hack. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
UIImage *img = [UIImage
    imageWithCGImage:[rep fullScreenImage]
    scale:[rep scale]
    orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

Is correct as under iOS 5 the fullscreenimages is already rotated (so it’s always “up”). Under iOS 4 the behaviour is different. Please see [Orientation does not behave correctly with Photo in ALAsset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832547/orientation-does-not-behave-correctly-with-photo-in-alasset/9447468#9447468) for a more in depth explanation.

Comment: Hello, Hendrik, and thanks again for the answer! I’ll submit a bug request against the documentation then, as it does not really make clear that the second paragraph only applies to iOS4. PS: you might want to leave out the signature from your posts, see [this meta thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed).

Comment: Submitted as [rdar://11604456](http://openradar.appspot.com/11604456) and resolved a month later in the upcoming iOS 6 release by leaving out the second, slightly confusing paragraph.

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling with this (and other related problems) for close to a week now. This is the first answer that actually made sense and worked for iOS5/iOS6. You are my hero ;)

Comment: thank you very much. This solution is also valid for iOS7.0.6.

Comment: You rock! I was using `[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]]` and your solution fixed the rotation problem, thank you! (Works on iOS 8.1)