# User-Notification Did Receive Response Method Does not allow me to Pass Updated Variable to UIApplication.shared.open() ?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, nsusernotification

I'm asking `UIApplication.Shared.Open()` method to open default Message App in IOS. I've implemented UserNotification, where and `userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) { }` method is called, I want to open default Messaging App with this URL.

```
schemeHere = "sms:/open?addresses=1115555648583&body=lllll"
```

It works fine for all the states of the application with this static variable. i-e `.active .background .inactive`.

The problem arises when through some logic I'm trying to provide an updated value of `schemeHere` for every notification.

The program doesn't accepts the updated value.
Here is my complete code for preference.

```
// For handling tap and user actions
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    self.reloadEasy()



    //let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
    //let carrier = networkInfo.subscriberCellularProvider

    // Get carrier name
    var countryCodeH = ""
    if let countryCode = (Locale.current as NSLocale).object(forKey: .countryCode) as? String {
        print(countryCode)
        countryCodeH = self.phoneCodes[countryCode]!
    }


    //var numbersH = ""
    //var messageH = ""
    //var schemeHere = ""

            let notifIdentifier = response.notification.request.identifier
            print(notifIdentifier)
            if notifIdentifier.contains("sms")
            {

                //open(scheme: schemeHere)
                /*
                var chrArr = Array(notifIdentifier.characters)
                chrArr.removeFirst()
                chrArr.removeFirst()
                chrArr.removeFirst()

                notifIdentifier = String(chrArr)


                var fullNameArr = notifIdentifier.characters.split{$0 == "_"}.map(String.init)

                let numbers = fullNameArr[1]
                messageH = fullNameArr[2]

                numbersH.removeAll()

                for c in numbers.characters
                {
                    if c != " "
                    {
                        numbersH.append(c)
                    }

                }

                print(messageH)
                print(numbersH)

                // "sms:/open?addresses=1-408-555-1212,1-408-555-2121,1-408-555-1221&body=/*message*/"
                //sms:/open?addresses=(555)564-8583&body=/*No Bofy*/
                schemeHere = "sms:/open?addresses=1" + numbersH + "&body=" + messageH

                //schemeHere1-408-555-1212,1-408-555-2121,1-408-555-1221, = "sms:/open?addresses=542-342-3423,23232323&body=/*No Bofy*/"

                schemeHere = "sms:/open?addresses=5555648583&body=lllll"


                */

    let state: UIApplicationState = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
    if state == .active {

        self.showMessage(message: "Active \(countryCodeH)")
        //let schemeHere = "sms:/open?addresses=1-408-555-1212,1-408-555-2121,1-408-555-1221,92-315-5849537&body=/*message*/"

        self.open(notifIdentifier: notifIdentifier)
    }
    else if state == .background
    {
        self.showMessage(message: "Background \(countryCodeH)")

        self.open(notifIdentifier: notifIdentifier)
    }
    else if state == .inactive
    {
        self.showMessage(message: "In-Active \(countryCodeH)")
        //let schemeHere = "sms:/open?addresses=14085551212,14085552121,14085551221,923155849537&body=/*message*/"

        self.open(notifIdentifier: notifIdentifier)
    }
    else
    {
        self.showMessage(message: "Un-defined State \(countryCodeH)")
        //let schemeHere = "sms:/open?addresses=14085551212,14085552121,14085551221,923155849537&body=/*message*/"

        self.open(notifIdentifier: notifIdentifier)
    }


   }
 }
```

Here is the function being called.

```
func open(notifIdentifier: String) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

    var numbersH = ""
    var messageH = ""
    var schemeHere = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253175/how-to-tell-if-blocks-in-loop-all-have-completed-executing"

    //open(scheme: schemeHere)
    var chrArr = Array(notifIdentifier.characters)
    chrArr.removeFirst()
    chrArr.removeFirst()
    chrArr.removeFirst()

    let notifIdentifierSecond = String(chrArr)


    var fullNameArr = notifIdentifierSecond.characters.split{$0 == "_"}.map(String.init)

    let numbers = fullNameArr[1]
    messageH = fullNameArr[2]

    numbersH.removeAll()

    for c in numbers.characters
    {
        if c != " "
        {
            numbersH.append(c)
        }

    }

    print(messageH)
    print(numbersH)

    // "sms:/open?addresses=1-408-555-1212,1-408-555-2121,1-408-555-1221&body=/*message*/"
    //sms:/open?addresses=(555)564-8583&body=/*No Bofy*/
    schemeHere = "sms:/open?addresses=1" + numbersH + "&body=" + "Wanted to Inform You!"

    //schemeHere1-408-555-1212,1-408-555-2121,1-408-555-1221, = "sms:/open?addresses=542-342-3423,23232323&body=/*No Bofy*/"
    //sms:/open?addresses=15555648583&body=Wanted to Inform You!

    //schemeHere = "sms:/open?addresses=1115555648583&body=lllll"


    let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {


    print(schemeHere)

    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2 // change 2 to desired number of seconds
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
            // Your code with delay




    if let url = URL(string: schemeHere) {
        print("Inside URL")
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            print("Now Doing in IOS 10.")
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:],
                                      completionHandler: {
                                        (success) in
                                        print("Open \(schemeHere): \(success)")
            })
        } else {
            let success = UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            print("Open \(schemeHere): \(success)")
        }

        }
        else
        {

            print("Inside Scheme!")
            print(schemeHere)
        }


        }

        print("test")
        }

     // UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string: schemeHere) as! URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

     })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some demonstrated time, I am able to clarify this by doing this in the following way.

Firstly, function open(URL) was called before, so there was a need of putting my code in dependant blocks, i-e using IOS GCD (Grand Central Dispatch).

I've created two functions and putted them in `dispatch_Group`.

Here is my code:

```
// Function A
func functionA_With_Dispatch(identif: String) -> String
{
    dispatch_group.enter()

    if identif.contains("sms")
    {

    var numbersH = ""
    var messageH = ""
    var schemeHere = ""

    var chrArr = Array(identif.characters)
    chrArr.removeFirst()
    chrArr.removeFirst()
    chrArr.removeFirst()

    let notifIdentifierSecond = String(chrArr)


    var fullNameArr = notifIdentifierSecond.characters.split{$0 == "_"}.map(String.init)

    let numbers = fullNameArr[1]
    messageH = fullNameArr[2]

    numbersH.removeAll()

    for c in numbers.characters
    {
        if c != " "
        {
            numbersH.append(c)
        }

    }

    print(messageH)
    print(numbersH)

    // "sms:/open?addresses=1-408-555-1212,1-408-555-2121,1-408-555-1221&body=/*message*/"
    //sms:/open?addresses=(555)564-8583&body=/*No Bofy*/
    schemeHere = "sms:/open?addresses=1" + numbersH + "&body=" + "Wanted to Inform You!"

    //schemeHere1-408-555-1212,1-408-555-2121,1-408-555-1221, = "sms:/open?addresses=542-342-3423,23232323&body=/*No Bofy*/"
    //sms:/open?addresses=15555648583&body=Wanted to Inform You!
    //Open sms:/open?addresses=1115555648583&body=lllll: true

    schemeHere = "sms:/open?addresses=\(numbersH)&body=\(messageH)"


    print(schemeHere)
    dispatch_group.leave()
    return schemeHere
  }


  dispatch_group.leave()
  return "empty"

}
```

Other function for opening URL.

```
func open_URL_With_Dispatch(schemeHere : String)
{
    dispatch_group.enter()


    if let url = URL(string: schemeHere) {
        print("Inside URL")
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            print("Now Doing in IOS 10.")
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:],
                                      completionHandler: {
                                        (success) in
                                        print("Open \(schemeHere): \(success)")


                                        self.dispatch_group.leave()
            })
        } else {
            let success = UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            print("Open \(schemeHere): \(success)")
            dispatch_group.leave()
        }

    }
    else
    {

        print("Inside Scheme!")
        print(schemeHere)
        dispatch_group.leave()
    }


}
```

Now in `userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) { }`, the work is here.

**NOTE: `dispatch_group` is declared at the top of the viewController.**

```
    dispatch_group = DispatchGroup()

    let notifIdentifier = response.notification.request.identifier
    self.reloadEasy()
    let schemeHere = self.functionA_With_Dispatch(identif: notifIdentifier)

    dispatch_group.wait()


   /*
    switch response.actionIdentifier {
    case "action1":

        if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
            print("SMS services are available")
            self.sendMessage(recipients: ["243243"], message: "ewhrewuew")


        }
        else
        {
            self.showMessage(message: "Can't send sms!")
            print("Can't send sms!")
        }

    default:
        if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
            print("SMS services are available")
            self.sendMessage(recipients: ["243243"], message: "ewhrewuew")
        }
        else
        {
            self.showMessage(message: "Can't send sms!")
            print("Can't send sms!")
        }
    } // Message Switch


    */



    let state: UIApplicationState = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
    if state == .active {

        self.showMessage(message: "Active")
        //let schemeHere = "sms:/open?addresses=1-408-555-1212,1-408-555-2121,1-408-555-1221,92-315-5849537&body=/*message*/"

        //self.open(notifIdentifier: notifIdentifier)


        self.open_URL_With_Dispatch(schemeHere: schemeHere)
    }
    else if state == .background
    {
        self.showMessage(message: "Background")

        //self.open(notifIdentifier: notifIdentifier)

        self.open_URL_With_Dispatch(schemeHere: schemeHere)
    }
    else if state == .inactive
    {
        self.showMessage(message: "In-Active")
        //let schemeHere = "sms:/open?addresses=14085551212,14085552121,14085551221,923155849537&body=/*message*/"

        //self.open(notifIdentifier: notifIdentifier)

        self.open_URL_With_Dispatch(schemeHere: schemeHere)
    }
    else
    {
        self.showMessage(message: "Un-defined State")
        //let schemeHere = "sms:/open?addresses=14085551212,14085552121,14085551221,923155849537&body=/*message*/"

        //self.open(notifIdentifier: notifIdentifier)

        self.open_URL_With_Dispatch(schemeHere: schemeHere)
    }
```

Secondly, I've found one other problem after doing so, where I was passing **spaces** and **newLines** in the URL string, but now I'm replacing them in the following way for the whole URL.

```
                for c in messageHere.characters
                {
                    if c == " "
                    {
                       appendedMessage.append("%20")
                    }
                    else if c == "\n"
                    {
                       appendedMessage.append("%0A")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       appendedMessage.append(c)
                    }
                }
```